# Some of Pandas subplots is blank or not displayed correctly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, pandas-datareader

I am trying to create subplots using a Pandas DataFrame but some of them are blank and not displayed correctly. I don't know where I made a mistake. Pandas Data Reader sometimes gives an error when receiving data from FRED, when I convert subplots to seaborn scatterplots in such errors, the problem is solved, but what I need is a line plot. What should I do in that case? Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr 
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime (2000,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime (2021,5,1)
df  = pdr.DataReader(['FDHBFRBN', 
                      'FDHBFIN',
                      'FYGFDPUN',
                      'FRDGBSAM',
                      'HBFRGDQ188S',
                      'MTSMFBP133FMS',
                      'GFDEGDQ188S',
                      'GFDEBTN',
                      'FYFSD',
                      'FYFSGDA188S'], 'fred', start, end)
df.columns = ['Federal Debt Held by Federal Reserve Banks',
              'Federal Debt Held by Foreign and International Investors', 
              'Federal Debt Held by the Public ',
              'Federal Reserve Bank Held Gold Bullion: On Display',
              'Federal Debt Held by Federal Reserve Banks as Percent of Gross Domestic Product',
              'Means of Financing: Borrowing from the Public',
              'Federal Debt: Total Public Debt',
              'Federal Debt: Total Public Debt',
              'Federal Surplus or Deficit',
              'Federal Surplus or Deficit [-] as Percent of Gross Domestic Product']
axes = df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(5,2), figsize=(15,25), linewidth=2, colormap="summer")
for (ax,), col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    ax.axvspan('2007-1-12', '2009-6-1', color='teal', alpha=0.5,
               label='2008 Crisis')
    ax.axvspan('2019-12-1', '2020-2-1', color='orange', alpha=0.5,
               label='Pandemic')
    ax.set_title(col)
    
axes[0,0].set_title('Federal Debt Held by Federal Reserve Banks')
axes[0,0].set_ylabel('Billions of Dollars(Quarterly)')
axes[0,0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[0,1].set_title('Federal Debt Held by Foreign and International Investors')
axes[0,1].set_ylabel('Billions of Dollars(Quarterly)')
axes[0,1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[1,0].set_title('Federal Debt Held by the Public ')
axes[1,0].set_ylabel('Millions of Dollars(Quarterly)')
axes[1,0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[1,1].set_title('Federal Reserve Bank Held Gold Bullion: On Display ')
axes[1,1].set_ylabel('Fine Troy Ounces(Monthly)')
axes[1,1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[2,0].set_title('Federal Debt Held by Federal Reserve Banks as Percent of Gross Domestic Product')
axes[2,0].set_ylabel('Percent of GDP(Quarterly)')
axes[2,0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[2,1].set_title('Means of Financing: Borrowing from the Public')
axes[2,1].set_ylabel('Millions of Dollars(Monthly)')
axes[2,1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[3,0].set_title('Federal Debt: Total Public Debt as Percent of Gross Domestic Product ')
axes[3,0].set_ylabel('Percent of GDP(Quarterly)')
axes[3,0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[3,1].set_title('Federal Debt: Total Public Debt')
axes[3,1].set_ylabel('Millions of Dollars(Qaurterly)')
axes[3,1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[4,0].set_title('Federal Surplus or Deficit')
axes[4,0].set_ylabel('Billions of Dollars(Annual)')
axes[4,0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

axes[4,1].set_title('Federal Surplus or Deficit [-] as Percent of Gross Domestic Product')
axes[4,1].set_ylabel('Percent of GDP(Annual)')
axes[4,1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))


ax.set_title("US Reserves")
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.family':'Latin Modern Sans'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop should be like this instead.

```py
for ax, col in zip(axes.flatten(), df.columns):
   ...
```

You need to flatten the `axes` grid, making in one dimensional, otherwise the `zip` function won't work properly, hence the empty plots.

Comment: when ı do axes.flatten() it gives an error like these: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object

Comment: Some suplots are not showing the data after 2012 and 2013 weirdly as well :(

Comment: Have you replaced your `(ax,)` with just `ax` ? I've copy-pasted your code, and just editing this line made all your subplots work for me.

Comment: @ounaldi This is the result: https://i.imgur.com/xcWX3bP.png

Comment: Yes, I replaced and now showing subplots better, but in some in most of the subplots , the datan after 2010 is not visualized. What should I do for that?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YdDrgcg @Xelvoz this is my result

Comment: I changed plot type as area plot instead of lineplot, now all plots showing correctly as hell. Thank you @Xelvoz